# php регулярка для даты вида Y.m.d H:i

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите, пожалуйста, написать регулярку для даты вида `Y.m.d H:i`. Еще как-нибудь нужно учесть, что дата введенная должна быть после сегодняшнего дня. Возможно, это тоже можно проверить в регулярном выражении?

Comment: а зачем вам регулярка? Есть `date_create()`, а уже потом можно с датами играться и проверять как они соотносятся с текущей датой

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php

Comment: @ArchDemon может `date_create()` ?

Comment: @Alpha, верно. очепятка

Comment: Еще может подойти вариант в комментарии к функции: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.checkdate.php

Answer (score 2):

```
return (bool)preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}\.[0-1][0-2]\.[0-3][0-9] [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$/",$date);
```

Но она не проверит на правильность даты, только на формат. Дополнять до правильности надо еще через или и группы. И то есть риск что-то пропустить.

Я бы использовал другой механизм, например [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $date);
return $dt !== false && !array_sum($dt::getLastErrors());
```

Этот подход с легкостью и проверит свежесть даты.